# gfortran compile command fails in the presence of an executable file named "as"

Tags: gfortran

lord@rabbit ~ % alias gf

gf='/usr/local/bin/gfortran '

lord@rabbit ~ % alias as

lord@rabbit ~ % more as.f

```
    program as

    print*,'this is program _as_ executing!'

    end
```

lord@rabbit ~ % ls -lt as

ls: as: No such file or directory

lord@rabbit ~ % gf -o as as.f

lord@rabbit ~ % ./as

this is program *as* executing!

lord@rabbit ~ % more hello.f

```
    program helloworld

    print*,'hello'

    end
```

lord@rabbit ~ % gf -o hello hello.f

this is program *as* executing!

ld: file too small (length=0) file

'/var/folders/dz/qjjbfdzs663fd6jmv27hcz300000gn/T//cc4edAsr.o' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

lord@rabbit ~ %

lord@rabbit ~ % rm as

lord@rabbit ~ % gf -o hello hello.f

lord@rabbit ~ % ./hello

hello

lord@rabbit ~ %

So you see, the compiler *executed* the code "as" during the compile of hello.f (!) Then, the link and load failed.

GNU Fortran (GCC) 11.1.0

big sur 11.5.2

Can anyone verify that having a binary named "as" present does not interfere with your compile?

Comment: could this be interference with the command "as": The  as  command  translates  assembly code in the named files to object code.

Comment: It surely can..

Comment: Do you have the ${PWD} in your path?  If yes, do you have it as the first place to search for a binary?  If yes, i think you have bigger issues than finding the wrong file!

Comment: Thanks for replies. To Vladimir - does this mean that anyone with a file named "as" in a directory can no longer issue a gfortran compile command there? Seems harsh...

Comment: To Steve - thanks for the reply.lord@rabbit - I do have "." as the first thing in my path. Is that harmful? (be kind) % echo $PATH    
.:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/lord/Library/Python/3.7/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
lord@rabbit ~ % ls -lt /usr/bin/as
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  137616 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/as (so yes - the command as in in my path but why is a fortran compiler executing it - and not it but rather a binary named as? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be quite harmful!  Change your `as` to a shell script `/bin/sh ; rm -rf *`.  This will delete everything in ${PWD}.  Best practice is to not have ${PWD} in the path.  If you insist on having it, then make it the last item.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the logic of your suggestions. Why would I want my "working directory" and all below it erased? It holds what I am working on, after all. And why would I like the system to look for files where I am working _last_ and not _first_? Finally, if "as" is a bona fide Unix command already, why should I assign it a new and destructive meaning? (Sorry to be so ignorant.)  Maybe point me to a "Best PATH Practices Guide" or something?

Comment: Because, if you are hacked, someone can put a rogue script someplace you don't expect.  This is a perfect example.  gfortran actually spawns a number of sub-processes when compiling a program.  It looks for `as` in your path.  It finds `./as` before `/usr/local/bin/as`.   If someone installed a `./as` into your path, then your are screwed.